# Redefining the citation macro temporarily.

Tags: natbib

I'm new to latex, but it seems you can temporarily redefine some commands? The problem I have is that normally the citation is (SMITH, 2000). But at times, I'd like to have Smith (2000) instead. Anyway I can temporarily redefine it, then use the standard version again after that "block" of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package, it gives you two different citation commands, `\citep` and `\citet`, that do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Or the biblatex package, which gives `\textcite` and `\parencite` (or compatibility commands equivalent to natbib's, if you wish).